# Что нужно дописат в коде, чтобы при обновлении страницы тема сохранялась?

Tags: javascript

````
var themeButton = document.querySelector('.theme-button');

themeButton.onclick = function() {
    page.classList.toggle('dark-theme');
    page.classList.toggle('light-theme');
};```
````

Comment: добавлять в LocalStore и потом делать проверку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У нас командой есть свой сайт: https://modulo-offic.github.io/

Данную проблемы мы решили через `cookie`. Но как сказали выше, есть localStorage, который желательнее использовать: https://learn.javascript.ru/localstorage

Что юзать - решать вам)